# Get parameters from url with .php already removed

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have got my urls rewriting, removing .php and replacing with a /

currently the .htaccess looks like this -

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

although now, I am trying to pass a GET parameter,

When i add this to the .htaccess -

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public_profile.php?params=$1 [NC]
```

or this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public_profile/params=$1 [NC]
```

And navigate to localhost/pages/public_profile/myparam

I get an internal server error.

I've also tried putting the .htaccess in side the pages/public_profile directory with

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?params=$1 [NC]
```

And when I navigate to http://localhost/pages/public_profile/

and print $_GET , "index.php" is printed

Can any one point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is `/pages/` a directory? Is .htaccess inside `/pages/` ?

Comment: pages is a directory yes, and no the .htaccess is inside the root ie. localhost/

Comment: So you want only last part as get parameter with the name as `params=` ?

Comment: Yes, so  localhost/pages/public_profile/myparam would let me print "myparam" from the params get variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a separate rule for handling get parameter:

```
RewriteEngine On    

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?params=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Now when i go to http://localhost/pages/public_profile/myparam , I get page not found